# Yii form not rendering in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2

I'm very new to Yii so I'm not sure if this is a mess up on my part or not.

I'm trying to loop through an array of rendered remote search forms and have the innerHTML display the correct form based on the index of whichever search type the user chose.

Whenever I put the php form render into the array, all of my other innerHTML objects stop appearing. Also, the forms themselves won't appear.

When I render the forms in HTML, they work with no problems, only when I try to render them in Javascript is there an issue.

Does anyone possibly have a solution to this?

Here is my code:

View:

```
<div class="search-tabs-new animated fadeInUp">
<!-- Create select box for user to choose search method (by Person, Phone or Address) -->
<div class="home-search-custom-select">
  <ul class="home-search-method-options-list">
    <li id="home-search-by-btn">Search By...</li>
    <li class="home-search-method-option"></li>
    <li class="home-search-method-option"></li>
    <li class="home-search-method-option"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="home-search-form-area">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let methodTypes = [
  'Phone Number',
  'Name',
  'Address'
];

let homeSearchForms = [

  '<?= $this->render('/site/forms/phone_search', ['uri' => Url::to(['phone/process'])]); ?>',
  '<?= $this->render('/site/forms/person_search', ['uri' => Url::to(['people/process'])]); ?>',
  '<?= $this->render('/site/forms/address_search', ['uri' => Url::to(['address/process'])]); ?>'

];

let searchMethodOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.home-search-method-option');
searchMethodOptions = Array.from(searchMethodOptions);

function setSearchMethod() {
  for (var i = 0; i < searchMethodOptions.length; i++) {
    const searchMethodOption = searchMethodOptions[i];
    const methodType = methodTypes[i];
    const searchForm = homeSearchForms[i];

    searchMethodOption.innerHTML = methodType;

    searchMethodOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById('home-search-form-area').innerHTML = searchForm;
    });

  }
}

setSearchMethod();
```

Comment: Look at the browser console for js errors, and be more specific about the issue

Comment: where is the html/forms that you are using in the javascript , add that html too as it is hard to guess like this , and are there any errors on the console

Comment: you need to show how you are using the above javascript snippet in your view, if you are using `heredoc` to include the above javascript it might not work correctly, please add your view code.

Comment: Just added in the HTML - so far no console js errors that I can see, I tried adding in an alert where the searchForm variable is being called as well as some standard HTML and they both worked fine. The problem seems to only happen when I'm calling the forms themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are line breaks in the HTML you render, you should remove those

```
let homeSearchForms = [

  '<?= preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $this->render('/site/forms/phone_search', ['uri' => Url::to(['phone/process'])])); ?>',
   ...

];
```

and also make sure you don't have any single quotes in the rendered HTML

Comment: That fixed the problem!! Thanks so much!